# dynamically change image in ImageStringElement as part of monotouch.dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

My problem is as follows:
I am creating a section with a number of ImageStringElements that when selected an audio file will play, e.g.

```
Section s = new Section(); 
foreach (var idea in ideas)
{
    s.Add(new ImageStringElement(idea.Id, delegate {ElementTapped();}, playImage));
}
```

Now when one of the elements is tapped, I would like to change the playImage to another one, i.e. PauseImage. Then again, when is it selected it changes back to the PlayImage. Not sure how to do this in the ElementTapped() method. Basically I would like to have a similar functionality as in the voice memos app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subclass ImageStringElement and make two changes:

Add:

```
class FlippingImageElement : ImageStringElement
{
    UIImage currentImage;
    UITableViewCell currentCell;

    public FlippingImageElement (string caption, UIImage image) : base (caption, image)
    {
        currentImage = image;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (tv);
        cell.ImageView.Image = currentImage;
        currentCell = cell;
    }

    public void SetImage (UIImage image)
    {
        currentImage = image;
        if (currentCell != null)
            currentCell.ImageView.Image = currentImage;
    }
}
```

Use this new element instead of the MonoTouch.Dialog one, and call the SetImage API to change the image

Comment: thanks for this. However, how do I call `SetImage` within `ElementTapped()` and automatically update the current cell with that image in the Section?

Comment: flipping.Tapped += delegate { flipping.SetImage (anotherImage); }

Comment: Nice. It works after a couple of minor changes in the code above, i.e. change `public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        base.GetCell (tv);
        cell.ImageView.Image = image;
        currentCell = cell;
    }` to `public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell (tv);
        cell.ImageView.Image = currentImage;
        currentCell = cell; return currentCell;
    }`